# How to consolidate multiple sales orders into one invoice?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is it possible to consolidate multiple sales orders into one invoice, and on the same note consolidate multiple sales orders to one PO? For example:

1. SO-0001 VendorA CustomerA USD1000
2. SO-0002 VendorA CustomerA USD1450

Which normally creates two different invoices and special PO's. Is it possible to consolidate it into one invoice, sales order or PO?

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a map/reduce to search/close/consolidate/invoice Sales Orders.

M/R script would be:

- Input: Search for open sales orders
- Map: Close Sales Orders and pass item data
- Reduce: Generate a new consolidated Sales Order and Invoice
- Summary: Email vendor (?)

As long as the search criteria is right, you shouldn't have any issues. And for POs, instead of invoicing, just set the Dropship/Intercompany settings instead of generating the Invoice, and set the order to Pending Fulfillment.

Comment: Hi @felipechang, I've tried using a M/R script but it seems that it takes all of open sales orders and turns them into Cash Sales or Invoice. Is it possible to mix a Reduce script to a User Event? (Where the user will select which customer and order to reduce? Thanks

Comment: You could perform the same action on afterSubmit, but it would have an impact on performance for the user (page would take longer to save). POs aren't normally created directly from Sales Orders, these are generated at line level whenever you configure it to be either DropShip or Intercompany (that's on the help files).

Comment: would you have an example? Not sure how to do it. Thanks.